# styles not applying in hot mail email template

Tags: css, html, hotmail, email-templates

I have a table in my email template. I applied styles to right align the text inside the td. But when i check them using hotmail the style tag looks empty. I tried `align="right"` inside the td. But nothing happens.

Html:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right" >Test Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I'd guess Hotmail disables tables. It's a crap shoot when it comes to doing anything fancy in emails. I've found this to be a great resource:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/

Comment: Try adding a div or a span inside your td and use text-align on those tags.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net for demo.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken I believe most email services will strip out inline styles. Most likely you will have to do all of the styling with HTML and tables.

**Try this and see what happens:**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
  <tr>
    <td>Test Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

All email services handle code differently so I would first look around google and see what kind of information you can find in regards to inline styles and Hotmail. Below are a couple links I found.

http://www.startupcto.com/marketing-tech/html-email/tips-and-tricks
http://www.webknowhow.net/dir/HTML/CSS/0607CSSSupportineMail.html